# Flot chart selection issue

Tags: flot

I am trying to implement a flot chart and i want some mechanism so that when i am selecting a region in the flot chart it remains within two data points in the chart,that is selection between intermediate points must not be possible.Can anyone suggest a way to do that?!

Answer (score 0):

A [bug](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=50) has existed for years asking for this enhancement to flot, and I haven't heard of anyone completing it.  Your best bet may be to start from the code there and implement it yourself.